# Dojo dgrid can have special rows listed on top

Tags: javascript, dojo, grid, dgrid

Can the dgrid have any functions to differentiate the rows? Data from server has two sets. One is the special set of rows that need to be displayed first on dgrid then the next set of data to be diaplayed with its own filter and sorting functions. Does dgrid support multiple data sets/store? Have to display the first data set all the time even while scrolling. I know that i can have two dgrids to accomplish this. Is it possible with one dgrid?

Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't anything out of the box to help with something like this.  I would suggest having two grids, one on top of the other, with the second having `showHeader` set to `false`.  If you need to hijack the sort behavior of the header cells within the first grid, you can listen for the grid's `dgrid-sort` event, cancel it (with `preventDefault`), and programmatically perform operations on the second grid.